# Toggle between two tabs in Firefox

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut for toggling back and forth to the last visited tab in Firefox like alt-tab behaves in Windows?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MicTech is correct, but by default Firefox will scroll through the tabs in order of opening. If you want to toggle between 2 tabs among more than 2, then use the wonderful [TabMixPlus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/) addon. With this you can set CTRL + TAB to toggle between the two most recently used. Has a whole heap of other great functions.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Yes, I think **Ctrl+Tab** is what you need.

And you can improve this function via some addons for FF.

*Also Ctrl+Shift+Tab to go backwards.* – Nick Josevski

Comment: yep @MicTech is correct!

Comment: Also Ctrl+Shift+Tab to go backwards.

Comment: If you have more tabs you can press CTRL + 1 for the first, CTRL + 2 for the second etc, if you have more than 9, the last tab will always be number 9.

Comment: I am actually looking for behavior similar to alt-tab

Answer (score 5):

ctrl + pg up ; ctl + pg down

Comment: Again, I am actually looking for behavior similar to alt-tab

Answer (score 3):

For me, the easiest way to do it WITHOUT ANY ADDON is the following:

1. Type "about:config" on the top browser bar.
2. FF will warn you. Just click "Accept the Risk!" or something like that
3. Type "ctrl" on the search bar (without the quotations)
4. Go to browser.ctrlTab.previews. It will say "False". Double click it so it may change to "True"

Now you can fully enjoy jumping between two tabs whenever you want by using Ctl+Tab keys. Just go to the first tab you want to work with, then to the second tab. Now FF has registered the both tabs so you can jump only between them.

I hope this Works for you. Good luck!

Comment: I'm on Firefox 64.0 and the option now seems to be `browser.ctrlTab.recentlyUsedOrder`, set it to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac: <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Right arrow</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Left arrow</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

The [FLST Firefox Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flst-firefox-29-plus/) gives you the option to switch between the two most recent tabs with Ctrl+.

Answer (score 0):

`CTRL`+ the number of the tab you want to go...

EX: `Consider 5 tabs`

`CTRL+4` goes to the 4th tab`...